# Most efficient way to turn a 5D array into a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe

I have a 5D array called predictors with a shape of `[6,288,37,90,107]` where `6` is the number of variables,
`288` is the time series of those variables,
`37`is the k locations,
`90` is the j locations,
`107` is the i locations.
 I want to have a `pandas dataframe` that includes columns of each variable timeseries at each `k,j,i` location so that of course will be a lot of columns.
Then I would like to somehow obtain the names for each column.
For example the first column would be `var1_k_j_i = predictors[0,:,0,0,0]`
except in the name I actually want the `k location`, `j location`,
and `i location` instead of `k_j_i`.
Since there are so many I can't do this by hand so I was hoping for a suggestion on the best way to organize this into a pandas dataframe and obtain the names? A loop possibly?

So in summary by the end of this I would like my 5D array of predictors turned into a large pandas dataframe where each column is a variable located at different k,j,i locations with the corresponding names of the variable and location in the header or first row of the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like you need to have fun with reshape here.

To address the location i,j,k is easy as using reshape. Then I'm not sure if you can reshape again to obtain a 2D representation of what you need, so I'm proposing a loop for you as follow.

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

dfs = []
new_matrix = matrix.reshape([6,288,37*90*107])
for var range(6):
   iterator = itertools.product(range(37), range(90), range(107))
   columns = ['var%i_' % var + '_'.join(map(str, x)) for x in iterator]
   dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(new_matrix[var]))

result = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: Hey, i guess you figured it out. I renamed all the 'feature' variable to 'var' but one slip through! I've just amended it.